# Cypress: Value from my cy.task() is not being assigned to a variable I have in my test

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

My empty variable that is supposed to be filled with return value from my cy.task() function, get_new_file_name().

```
    let uniqueFileName = ''
```

cy.task('get_new_file_name') basically takes a file name, increments the last digit at the end and return the new file name. This function works as intended.

```
get_new_file_name(file) {
  let split_file = file.split('.')
  const fixture_folder = 'cypress/fixtures/'
  const file_extension = '.' + split_file[1]
  const file_name = split_file[0]
  let incremented_file_name = file_name.replace(/(\d*)$/, (_, t) => (+t + 1)) 
  let old_file = `cypress/fixtures/${file_name}${file_extension}`
  let new_file = `cypress/fixtures/${incremented_file_name}${file_extension}`
  fs.renameSync(old_file, new_file)
  return new_file
    }
```

my code in test file:

```
    cy.task('get_new_file_name', uniqueFileName).then((res) => {
          const renamedfile = res
          cy.wrap(renamedfile).as('newfile').get('@newfile').then(res => {
            uniqueFileName = res;
            cy.log(uniqueFileName)
          }
          )
        });
```

All I'm trying to do is get the return value from my function to be assigned to a variable in my test file since i'll be using that variable later. Currently, after my code runs, I cy.log(uniqueFileName) and it keeps printing me the old value.

Answer (score 3):

Because `cy.log()` is a Cypress command, it takes the value to be logged when the test is first run but before the other commands have run.

You have two options, wrap another `.then()` or use `console.log` instead

```js
cy.task('get_new_file_name', uniqueFileName).then((res) => {
  const renamedfile = res
  uniqueFileName = res
  cy.then(() => {  
    cy.log(uniqueFileName)  // now it works
  })
```